# Autocomplete feature using Solr4 on multivalued fields

Tags: solr, autocomplete, solr4

I've seen posts on performing autocomplete across multiple fields but not on performing autocomplete on multivalued fields.

My autocomplete feature is working for non-multivalued fields.

My problem is when I run the query on the multivalued field, wherever a document matches that query, *all* the fields in the multivalued field of that document are returned in the facet results.

Below is my schema, similar to what is proposed in the Solr 4 Cookbook.

```
 <fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="publisherText-str" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="publisherText-ac" type="text_autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

As you can see publisherText is a multivalued field. I execute a query like this to test the autocomplete feature:

```
/select?q=publisherText-ac:new&facet=true&facet.field=publisherText-str&facet.mincount=1&rows=0
```

The query is "new", and this matches a set of documents. However the facet result set contains the other publisherText values (contained in the multivalued field) for each matching document.

**Update**: When querying "new", the result set should include "New York Times" and "Times New Roman" but does not need to solve the infix problem: "Knewton Gazette" does not need to be in the result set.

Is there a way to have the facet result only contain values that match the query?
Or is there a different (better?) way to support the full autocomplete feature that handles multiValued fields more gracefully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the most optimal way would be to create a separate collection or core (depending if you are using cloud or not) and have your data indexed in a way, that it can be queries for the desired query result. Of course it may not be possible in some cases, but if it is in your case go for it. In such core you would only have fields and data relevant to your autocomplete so in most cases it will be smaller, than the original core, less terms and that should result in faster queries. In addition to that, such core or collection optimized for autocomplete queries and you'll gain even more performance out of it.

However if you can't go for multiple cores/collections approach than highlighting may be the best way to go, if you need filtering. In such case you may want to have term verctors turned on and use FastVectorHighlighting to have better performance of Solr highlighting (http://solr.pl/en/2011/06/13/solr-3-1-fastvectorhighlighting/).

Comment: "have your data indexed in a way, that it can be queries for the desired query result" - isn't that what this question is about? You should be a bit more verbose in that matter: how can a separate core help here? Do you mean to normalize the data to guarantee that autocomplete results return no duplicates? Also, the question is not about performance but about an "autocomplete feature that handles multiValued fields more gracefully"? You have to show that maintaining a separate core just for autocomplete is worth the effort, and really can be sign. more performant than this solution already is.

Comment: The problem with a separate core is how to update it when you update the original core. For example, when you remove a document from the original core, how do you update the separate core? You need to remove data, but only if that data is not also provided by some other document. Reindexing the separate core from scratch is usually not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I have used these two ways, so far:

(A) stick to using facets and accept that you have to reduce the result via regular expression or String.startsWith. This might actually not be so bad if you use frontend components like the YUI3 Autocomplete plugin which offers this feature already without you having to do much about it.

(B) use highlighting by adding to your query:

```
&hl=true&hl.fl=publisherText-ac
```

For each hit, the highlighting component will return the matching value, including highlighting tags (by default `<em>`). This is even more helpful if your autocomplete field is sourced by several input fields and you don't want to search through the results to find out which field contains the matching value. The resulting list may contain duplicates, however.

I am using both approaches, (A) for autocomplete on single fields, (B) when sourcing autocomplete from multiple fields. I tried to get rid of the `<em>` tags included in the highlighting results but that has proven quite impossible (you can only change them but not remove them completely).

(using SOLR 4.0 over here)

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I guess you might find it interesting. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `facet.prefix=new` parameter and let solr filter those entries out for you.
What I would also consider is to avoid making ngrams here. Making a facet and using the `facet.prefix` does the trick already. Hopefully you will not have too many unique terms and performance will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. facet.prefix helps but doesn't fully solve the problem. The result set should include values for which any word matches. For example, if my query is "new" the result set should include "New York Times" and also "Times New Roman" (but does not need to support infix, "Knewton Gazette" does not have to be in the result set).

Comment: Ok, that's kind of a new problem. I would then look at the terms component, which does something similar but in a different way, and allows you to specify a regex instead of the only prefix in order to filter the results shown. Your schema might need to be changed too, and performance might be worse, depending on how many unique terms you have for that field.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at TermsComponent. Seems like it might have some limitations since I want to be able to filter as well. I'm thinking about setting up a separate core that indexes this publisher field in a denormalized way (each doc is a publisher). This index would then be dedicated to serving the autocomplete requests for this data, instead of having the data buried in a multivalued field.

Comment: Yes if you want to filter the only way is making a facet. The separate core idea is definitely the best one, that gives more flexibility but requires more effort as well. Good luck!